# Join layers in PyQGIS, on multiple fields

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-joins

Is it possible to join two layers in PyQGIS, on multiple fields?

ie, JOIN ON layer1field1 = layer2field1 AND layer1field2 = layer2field2

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is possible as this cannot be achieved via the GUI.

---

An alternative could be to **duplicate** *layer1* which would allow you to join each *layer1* with the relevant field of *layer2*.

Answer (score 1):

Your question uses the "AND" statement which suggest both field joins must be true for a feature to join.  With that another alternative approach would be:

- Create a new field called field3 in both layers
- Field calculate field3 with the concatenation of field1 and field2 for both layers
- Perform join on field3