# QGIS: String formatting when creating a virtual field

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I would like to join US census [population estimates](https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/popest/datasets/2010-2019/counties/totals/co-est2019-alldata.csv) with [county boundaries](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_county_5m.zip).

The population estimates layer (`co-est2019-alldata`) contains `STATE` and `COUNTY` fields with state and county FIPS codes, like this:

| STATE | COUNTY |
| --- | --- |
| 36 | 51 |
| 1 | 15 |

The county boundary (`cb_2018_us_county_5m`) layer contains the same values but with slightly different formatting and additionally a `GEOID` string field that combines the two:

| STATEFP | COUNTYFP | GEOID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 36 | 051 | 36051 |
| 01 | 015 | 01015 |

QGIS [doesn't support joining on multiple fields](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282297/join-layers-in-pyqgis-on-multiple-fields), but a common workaround is to create a new virtual field that combines the target attributes. I want to create a virtual field in the population layer that matches the `GEOID` field in the county boundary layer.

This would be simple if there were a function equivalent to `sprintf`, because then I could just write:

```
sprintf('%02s%03s', "STATE", "COUNTY")
```

...but as far as I can tell, no such function exists. What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Something like `right('0' || to_string("STATE"), 2) || right('00' || to_string("COUNTY"), 3)`.

Comment: or better : `lpad(to_string("STATE"), 2, '0') || lpad(to_string("COUNTY"), 3, '0')`.

Comment: @J.Monticolo perfect! Want to post that as an answer? I hadn't previously noticed those string functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one :

```py
lpad(to_string("STATE"), 2, '0') || lpad(to_string("COUNTY"), 3, '0')
```

*returns*

if `"STATE"` = `1` and `"COUNTY"` = `15` : `01015`
if `"STATE"` = `22` and `"COUNTY"` = `5` : `22005`

From the documentation:

- **lpad(`string`, `width`, `fill`)** ([doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=lpad#lpad)) :

  > Returns a string padded on the left to the specified width, using a fill character. If the target width is smaller than the string’s length, the string is truncated.
- **to_string(`number`)** ([doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=lpad#expression-function-string-to-string)) : (because I wasn't sure that your fields were characters)

  > Converts a number to string.
- **||** : concatenate two strings